# How do I create a CloudFront distribution without an origin for a self-contained lambda@edge function?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a small Node.js function on AWS Lambda that returns a very simple dynamic response, such as:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "Hello World " + Math.random(),
    };
    return response;
};
```

I want to deploy this on the public web through lambda@edge. To do this, I need to connect it to a CloudFront distribution. However, CloudFront requires that I choose an origin. This function doesn't need an origin.

Is it possible to deploy this without a CloudFront origin or do I need to create a dummy page, such as a static file on S3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create a dummy page. You can set an arbitrary domain name as the distribution origin.

If you use a function as a Viewer Request handler, you can set any domain name, for example `dev.null`.

If you use a function as an Origin Request handler, the domain name must be an existing valid name, for example `example.com`. As AWS support says, CloudFront performs a DNS validity check for the origin domain, but doesn't send requests to the domain (if the function returns a response).

Comment: Don't use `dev.null`. `null` could become a registered TLD at any time. To avoid potential future mistakes, use a domain name that is guaranteed not to become valid in future, for example something ending in `.invalid` (RFC 2606).

Comment: @jbg If `dev.null` becomes a valid domain with an active website, the solution won't break

Comment: I didn't say it would break. I said "to avoid potential future mistakes". Using a potentially-valid domain name means that if you ever adjust or remove your viewer request handler, you may accidentally end up serving responses from an untrusted origin. Even if the original asker of this question is immune to mistakes, this answer will be read by others too, so it should teach good engineering practices.